# I can't login to SharePoint 2010, what's wrong?

Tags: login

I have set up SharePoint 2010, created a web app + site collection, I'm using a domain account which is the site collection admin.

Everything appears "Peachy", until I get to the login prompt when accessing the site. The credentials simply don't work, and it keeps prompting for a login.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, this solved my issue on Windows Server 2008 R2 running SharePoint 2010.

ALSO AS DC! :) For all you purists!

Disable the loopback check loadTOCNode(2, 'workaround'); Follow these steps:

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
2. In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
3. Right-click Lsa, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
   Type DisableLoopbackCheck, and then press ENTER.
4. Right-click DisableLoopbackCheck, and then click Modify.
   In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.1.2.

RESTART PC!

Comment: I hope that's not a production box you've disabled loopbackcheck on, very bad practice.

Here's the a reason why: http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx

Comment: Nope, its development :)

Comment: Good good, just checking ;)

Comment: Unfortunly didn't work to me

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is to be sure you are domain qualifying your user name.  Sometimes it will want to default to machine name.

I've also seen this happen before when the SharePoint service jobs were set up to run with a local system account.   Are you able to browse the site from the server, just not from another workstation on the LAN?  If so, try changing the service jobs to use the network service account.