# Unable to login into site after restoring

Tags: restore, login

a continuation from here, [problem restoring sharepoint from backup](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34639/problem-restoring-sharepoint-from-backup)

after restoring from a back-up into the new site, i am unable to login despite changing the site collection administrator.

all logins via domain\username does not work.

however, i am able to login if i use the [CopmuterNameOfTheOldSPServer]\administrator ...

anyone can help me with this login configuration ?

thanks in advance.

found the problem at last :

it seems there's a fault in the C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

particularly this part of settings :

```
            <add name="SharePoint - 80" autoStart="true" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
            <processModel identityType="NetworkService" loadUserProfile="true" idleTimeout="00:00:00" />
            <recycling logEventOnRecycle="Time, Requests, Schedule, Memory, IsapiUnhealthy, OnDemand, ConfigChange, PrivateMemory">
            <periodicRestart time="00:00:00">
            <schedule>
            <clear />
            <add value="02:18:00" />
            </schedule>
            </periodicRestart>
            </recycling>
            <failure rapidFailProtectionMaxCrashes="10" />
            </add>
```

make sure line no 2  is  **"< processModel identityType="NetworkService" loadUserProfile="true" idleTimeout="00:00:00" / >"** and not anything else..

mine was something like specific account user...

Answer (score 3):

Hi I had the very same issue after restoring. The accepted solution by user879 to this question seems to help: 
[I can't login to SharePoint 2010, what's wrong?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5574/i-cant-login-to-sharepoint-2010-whats-wrong)  ([answer here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/5576/5173)). You can give it a try, but be aware that disabling the loopback could pose a threat as per the article posted by James in the comment - [disable loopback check & sharepoint](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the site collection admin for the site from central admin.

Go to Central Admin -> Manage Site collection admin -> select the required web app and site collection -> Enter primary and secondary administrator.

Since it has been restored from another farm, the site collection admin would be the old one and you probably won't be having any access. Try logging in as the primary or secondary admin.

**UPDATE**

Can you try the Powershell command  and do an **IISReset**

`Set-SPSite -Identity "<SiteCollection>" -SecondaryOwnerAlias "<User>"`

Comment: i have changed it and it still doesn't work .

Comment: Will update the answer for your comments. :) Good Luck.

Comment: nvm .. i found the culprit deep in the iis settings file.. i will update my findings. ..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue . I was able to access the site from the server as admin but not outside the server either as a normal user or admin.After restoring the content database from another farm.

Solution: Run the Upgrade-SPcontentDatabase ""

I retried with different user accounts and it started working now.

Hope this helps.!!